# Angularjs routes not working here

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used all possible way to solve this but failed.
If you have any query to understand this problem then let me know.
Below is my code and check if there any syntax error.
I have used local angular js file for route and try with cdn.
But nothing affect.

**Index.html**

```
 <!-- define angular controller -->
 <body  ng-app="mydemo" ng-controller="mainController">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about"></i> About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact"></i> Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

  <div ng-view></div>

<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

**Script.js**

I have used angularjs version of 1.5.7

```
     var mydemo = angular.module('mydemo', ['ngRoute']);
      mydemo.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        });
});

mydemo.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});

mydemo.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

mydemo.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
});
```

Comment: Do you see any console errors ?

Comment: yes,It is",Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider"

Comment: check the plunker i created based on your code https://plnkr.co/edit/EIGbhW2oQ3KAtn9A5t1h?p=preview It work fine, could you compare it with actual code.

Comment: The code is not able to recognize routeProvider. If you can check your angular router js file, in case that is correct or not. Also are you uglifying your code?

Comment: what versions of angular and ng-route are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<li><a href="#contact"></i> Contact</a></li>
```

how about trying

```
<li><a ng-href="#/contact"></i> Contact</a></li>
```

I think the routes have to match exactly, which includes the `/`.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this script.js file:

```
     angular.module('mydemo', ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        });
});

mydemo.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});

mydemo.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

mydemo.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
});
```

And index.html:

```
    <head>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

     <!-- define angular controller -->
     <body  ng-app="mydemo" ng-controller="mainController">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about"></i> About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact"></i> Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

      <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

Comment: yes,and it is "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider"

Comment: @SunnySingh please try only my updated answer script.js file

Comment: actually you have missed . after $routeProvider so the it should pe like $routeProvider.

Comment: @SunnySingh i think you should try ui router rather than ng-router if it is not working.

Comment: yeah i also used ui-router

Answer (score 0):

Check the fix below:

```
$routeProvider // there are two dots in your code here, just remove one and it will fix the issue
.when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
    controller  : 'mainController'
})
```

Comment: Nothing changes after all.

Comment: Did you try removing on dot ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that the version of angular you are using doesn't match the version of angular route. Make sure the versions are compatible.